# 'System.InvalidOperationException'. The error is: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, input, exception, type-conversion

When I try to run one of my subroutines when a textbox has a change in value, it throws this exception. The weird part is it works for the first textbox but when I tried it for every other one on the form it gave me this error. All of the textboxes have initialized text values so I don't see why it would be getting an empty String.

Comment: I can't share an image since I do not have 10 reputation points.

Comment: Hi, can you show us the code?

Comment: You would get an empty string if the user deleted the initialized value (perhaps prior to typing in a new value). You should certainly allow for the possibility that the TextBox is empty, as well as the possibility that the user enters something that is not a valid Integer.

Comment: @Blackwood So if I account for when the user deletes the input would that get rid of the exception? It's occurring when I try to run the application.

Comment: @JackPettinger Can I insert code snippets into comments?

Comment: Best to edit your original question to add the code you are using. And yes, if you avoid trying to convert the text to an Integer when the text is blank you won't get that particular exception. You should still check for other invalid text values. I suggest using `Integer.TryParse` to validate the text and convert to Integer.

Comment: @Blackwood Thank you, that worked. I knew I would have to add error handling but I didn't know it would yell at me like that. Used to having more control like in C. Again thanks for your help.